# PDF report for SONARQUBE Version 5.5

Tags: pdf, sonarqube, report

I currently installed SONARQUBE 5.5 and I have need for pdf reporting. Is there any free plugin available ? If there is any commercial plugin , what will be the cost and where to contact?

Comment: Do you mean the [Report](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Report+Plugin) plugin?

Comment: Report plugin is not available for 5.5 version , its been Governance Product for product but it commercial one. Is there any plugin for the same task? if not , may i know the cost of Governance plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of open-source plugins that provide such feature and that are currently compatible with latest SonarQube versions.

The only one I know is the [Governance product](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/plugins/governance.html). But it is available only on the [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/solutions/deployments/enterprise-grade/) provided by SonarSource.